# Confirm host fails for Single node Cluster while setting up cluster on Ambari

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, ambari, bigdata

I am trying to setup Ambari on single node cluster.
Ambari setup was done as root user
I tried all the post related to this , change the permission and did set up as permission
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.2.1/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_set_up_password-less_ssh.html

```
cd ~/.ssh
rm -rf /root/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t dsa
cat /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
cat  /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Copied the the Key from above line in Ambari while setting up cluster Step

```
ambari-server restart
```

When I try to Register and Confirm in lInstall Options I get below error
However I am able to do "ssh root@hadoop.maxsjohn.com without giving the password.

```
==========================
Creating target directory...
==========================

Command start time 2017-03-13 03:35:43

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
SSH command execution finished
host=hadoop.maxsjohn.com, exitcode=255
Command end time 2017-03-13 03:35:43

ERROR: Bootstrap of host hadoop.maxsjohn.com fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (255)
ERROR MESSAGE: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

STDOUT: 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).[Error Message][1]
```

[image: My Local settings]

Answer (score 1):

So, coming in a year later I got a very similar error but with a multiple host cluster.  In case it helps, I found this error happens for the host running Ambari Server when the private key file chosen on the 'Install Options' page in the 'Cluster Install Wizard' is incorrect (in my case I re-created the keys but neglected to update Ambari).  From the host OS perspective the passwordless SSH works just fine but Ambari fails to install the host until the corresponding SSH Private Key file is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the password cannot be blank. You need to set a password. If this is for your learning, i would suggest take a copy of VM from hortonworks site and use it. You don't have to go through the pain of installing and configuring. Here is the [link](https://hortonworks.com/downloads/#sandbox)